# Problem with jQuery pagination and putting an animate.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Question 1:** Why `not change pagination after click` (pagination page change but it no)?
I mean is here in my example (this not change after click):[image]
**EXAMPLE:** [My code](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/show)

**Question 2:** I want putting an `animate like this` for pagination table but stronger: http://jsfiddle.net/wY3Us/3/

Js code:

```
$('#pagination a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $.get( $(this).attr('href'), function(html) {
            $('table#paginate').replaceWith( $(html).find('table#paginate') );
        });
        return false;
    });
```

With respect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your javascript to this:

```
$('#pagination a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $.get( $(this).attr('href'), function(html) {
            $('table#paginate').replaceWith( $(html).find('table#paginate') );
        });
        return false;
    $('.pagination a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

And your html should look like this:

```
<div class="pagination">

 <a class="selected" href="http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/show/1">1</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/show/3">2</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/show/6">3</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/show/3">&gt;</a>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/hotel/show/9">Last > </a>  
 </div>
```

And make sure you have the following lines in your CSS:

```
div.pagination a.selected {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

#### GoodLuck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are giving wrong ID, your pagination links are on #pagination div, try

```
$('#pagination').replaceWith( $(html).find('#pagination') );
```

Comment: i test,no this, problem is other things. not know things!?

Comment: What about $('#pagination').html( $(html).find('#pagination').html() );   I can see you have now changed pagination from id to class, as you know for class .pagination will be used